# How to create a wrapper for non-creatable class?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I am working with the specific class library. All available value classes are derived from the base class. There are scalar types

```
oaBooleanValue : public oaValue
oaIntValue     : public oaValue
oaFltValue     : public oaValue
oaStringValue  : public oaValue
```

First 3 classes define method get() as returning value. And the 4th class defines get as taking a reference.

```
oaBoolean get() const;
oaInt     get() const;
oaFloat   get() const;
void      get(oaString& value) const;
```

I need to use all 4 classes in my template wrapper class uniformely.
I've written the auxiliary oaStringValueGetter class as below. But there is the problem. The base class oaValue restricts default constructor and copy-constructor. There is only one way to create instances by using static 'create()' method.

**Is there any way to add some type-cast methods to my class so it would automatically converts from oaStringValue?**

```
class oaStringValueGetter : public oaStringValue
{
public:
  oaString get() const
  {
    oaString str;
    oaStringValue::get(str);
    return str;
  }
};
```

And here is partial class definition taken from the library, for the reference

```
class oaObject {
public:
  // public methods are here

protected:
  ~oaObject();

private:
  oaObject();
  oaObject(const oaObject& obj);

  oaObject& operator=(const oaObject& obj);
};

class oaValue : public oaObject {
public:
  void                    destroy();
  oaBoolean               isEqual(oaValue *value) const;
  oaValue                 *copy() const;
};

class oaString; // library-defined custom string class

class oaStringValue : public oaValue {
public:
  static oaStringValue* create(oaObject* database, const oaString  &value);

  void get(oaString& value) const;
  void set(const oaString& value);
};

typedef int oaInt4;

class oaIntValue : public oaValue {
public:
  static oaIntValue* create(oaObject* database, oaInt4 value);

  oaInt4 get() const;
  void set(oaInt4 value);
};
```

Comment: If a class restricts all its constructors, it's impossible to subclass it.  Does `oaValue` have any public constructors at all?

Comment: You are right. It is not possible to write "class oaStringValueGetter : public oaStringValue" with the given conditions. I solved my task in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the concept of a wrapper vs a subclass.

A wrapper does not necessarily subclass the contained class, it may be composed of an *instance* of the contained class, wherein calls to the composing class are delegated to the composed class instead of direct inheritance.

In your case, having the wrappers contain instances of the wrapped classes and then delegating calls might be easier.

Comment: You are right. In my case there is one more condition I didn't mention initially :) oaObject-derived classes are created by the framework only. They are mahaged objects. If I spesify my own class it will not be handled by the framework. So, the variety of solutions is extremely limited here. Finally I solved it by writing more source code.

Comment: @VadimSukhorukov That's good that you solved it. Now post an answer to that effect and mark it as correct so other people can see at-a-glance that your question has been, well, answered. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a template function for getting value from object of type T by returning the result of object's get() method. It will be the default implementation for scalars. Then make a specialization of this template where T=oaString and temporary oaString variable is used to get string value as your interface requires. Return that variable as a result. Hope that'd help you